# How to get back to master branch using git?

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-bash

I unintentionally used the command `git checkout -b "branchname"` in the desktop but now I cannot return to the master branch anymore. I tried using `git checkout master` but it is not working. I'm using git bash. Anyone who can tell me how to return to master branch after such mistake?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: What's "not working"? Error message? What does `git branch` say?

Comment: It should work fine. What *does* happen? Are you sure you have a branch named `master`, rather than `main`? (GItHub recently changed the default name of a new repository to `main`.)

Comment: welcome to SO! I think you should paste the `git checkout` command you are running and output in the question.

Comment: `git branch` says nothing. Git bash is opening a new line for me with the same branch I created unintentionally

Comment: @chepner I'm using windows and git bash was showing my original branch with yellow highlights as master. Now it is showing me a blue branch. It was never main in my case

Comment: @eftshift0 when ever I'm using `git checkout` I'm shown this message: `fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`

Comment: Please click [edit], and explain as clearly as you can, in the question itself, what commands you have run, and what error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is *normal* behavior for a new repo with an **unborn branch**.

When you create a **new repo that doesn't have any commits yet**, the command `git checkout -b new-branch`, or it's newer equivalent command `git switch -c new-branch` actually changes the starting branch from `master` (or `main`) to that new branch name. So, your `master` branch in this case is literally gone. No worries though because like most things in Git, it's easy to get stuff back.

You could get back to where you started by renaming the branch (or in this edge case using the command to create a new branch) again with any one of these commands:

```
git checkout -b master
# or
git switch -c master
# or
git branch -m master # rename the current branch
```

Once you create a commit in the repo, you'll be able to see all your branches with `git branch` and then creating new branches will work as expected.

Comment: This is called an _unborn_ branch. (Note too the OP's error message, "You are on a branch yet to be born".)

Comment: @matt thx. I made that clearer now.

Comment: Cool. Nice detective work too. :)

Comment: By the way, even deleting a branch with commits does not (immediately) lose any commits. Let's not worry the beginners unnecessarily.

Comment: @matt agreed. Edited.